# Add custom variable to jquery datatables and read in search filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the jQuery DataTables plugin. I am trying to assign a parameter to my table, and use that parameter later in a custom search. I however cant find out how to store and get that parameter, and in my custom search i dont know how to get the table object. Here is my code to give a more clear idea of what i am trying to do:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var myParam = ....;
        console.log('i said: '+ myParam)
       return true;
    }
);

var table = jQuery('#myTable').DataTable();
table.myParam = 'hello';
table.draw();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use global variable:

  ```
  var myParam = '';

  jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {   
         console.log('i said: '+ myParam)
         return true;
      }
  );

  var table = jQuery('#myTable').DataTable();
  myParam = 'hello';
  table.draw();
  ```
- Use `data-` property:

  ```
  jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
         var table = new jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api( settings ); 
         var myParam = jQuery(table.table().node()).data('myParam');

         console.log('i said: '+ myParam)
         return true;
      }
  );

  var table = jQuery('#myTable').DataTable();
  jQuery(table.table().node()).data('myParam', 'hello');
  table.draw();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The data() seems a good idea, however it means that for each row check a new object will be created. Do you know if this has any impact on performance and on how to fix that? I am trying to avoid globals.

Comment: @user4493177, obviously with `data-` property method there are several extra functions that will be called in the loop. I'm not sure how that will impact performance, that will depend on the table size.